# Is there a way to monitor double clicks leading to duplicate requests?

Tags: javascript, duplicates, fiddler

I would like to browse my test site constantly manually double clicking on buttons and links to check if all double clicks are correctly blocked by the application.

Is there a way to see if double clicks by the user lead to duplicate requests? I guess there should be a way in fiddler or F12 tools or some chrome plugin.

I fancy a filter when applied to fiddler it would only show requests that happen multiple times.

Comment: Quick and dirty, on click disable the element

Comment: I am not looking to solve the problem. I try to test the application if that issue exists and want to automate it a bit.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: I dont yet have an issue with my application. I am trying to set up my tools to more easlily try out if I have an issue with double clicks.

Comment: I meant, if you can use jQuery, I can provide you an example, if you cannot, then I will provide you a different example. So, can you use jQuery?

Comment: I dont see were I would run a javascript command. My intention is to analyze my interaction with the application and I dont have access to it.

Comment: Why would you tag the question as javascript if you cannot use javascript? The fact that you said in F12 tools, I thought that you just wanted a little script to run while you were on the page. What do you mean that you don't have access to it? If you don't have access to it, you can do nothing with it?

Comment: I mentioned F12 tools as a way to intercept http requests of the browser. I tagged it Javascript because the application under test is  a single page application were duplicate requests might be an issue. I guess that there are some javascript developers who already thought about a  way to more easily test for these kind of issues. Apparently my question doesnt make it clear enough what I am up to. I will try to rephrase the question.